# underscore/lowdash passing reference to objectwhich I can't overwrite

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm using the _.find() methid of Lodash to find an object and I am then trying to overwrite that object, like this...

```
taskToUpdate = _.find($scope.tasks, {ID: myID});
taskToUpdate = {};
```

This finds the reference to the task perfectly, but does not set it to an empty object, it has no effect.

However, if i pick a particular property and overwrite it, it works...

```
taskToUpdate = _.find($scope.tasks, {ID: myID});
taskToUpdate.title = "New title";
```

That works fine. I have a feeling the problem here is not lodash, but my bad understanding of how objects and references are passed between functions in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're setting the local variable `taskToUpdate` to an empty object, meanwhile `$scope.tasks` still retains the original reference to the unaltered object.

Once you have the reference to the object you can then get the `indexOf`.

```
var index = _.indexOf($scope.tasks, taskToUpdate);
```

And then can blank out the object reference in the `$scope.tasks`

```
$scope.tasks[index] = {};
```

At this point the reference in `$scope.tasks` will be a blank plain object, but `tasksToUpdate` will continue to hold the object reference. You can choose to continue to use it at this point, or not. But once you've ended all closures that have a reference to that `taskToUpdate` object, it will cease to exist.

My guess is that you actually want to remove the reference from `$scope.tasks` rather than just blanking out the object reference. You can do this many ways, but here is one:

```
$scope.tasks = _.without($scope.tasks, taskToUpdate);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I thought that was the problem but had no idea how to get the actual object to manipulate it. IndexOf was the answer.